# Only one custom tableviewcell working correctly

Tags: swift, uitableview

I created a custom tableviewcell with a photo and two labels. I queried some data from parse and the cells are suppposed to update the image and labels to reflect the query, however only the first viewcell works correctly. The image and labels work, however the second viewcell only displays the image correctly, the uilabels do not display any text. I've looked over the code multiple times and cant seem to figure out what i am doing wrong...

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mySpotCell")/*, forIndexPath:  indexPath)*/as? CustomTableViewCell

         //   cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        if let value = mySpots[indexPath.row]["location"] {
            let location = CLLocation(latitude: (value.latitude)!, longitude: (value.longitude)!)

            self.geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemark, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                }
                if let pm: CLPlacemark = placemark![indexPath.row] {
                   // var pm = placemark![indexPath.row] as CLPlacemark
                    //self.parkingSpotAddress.text = pm.thoroughfare
                   // self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = pm.thoroughfare
                    //cell!.textLabel?.text = "\(pm.subThoroughfare!) \(pm.thoroughfare!)"
                    cell?.subtitleLabel.text = "\(pm.subThoroughfare!) \(pm.thoroughfare!)"
                    cell?.titleLabel.text = pm.description
                    print(cell?.subtitleLabel.text)
                    print(cell?.titleLabel.text)
                }
            })
            if let parkingSpotImageFile: PFFile = mySpots[indexPath.row]["firstPhoto"] as! PFFile! {
                parkingSpotImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        cell?.spotImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                       // self.imageIndicator.stopAnimating()
                       // self.imageIndicator.hidden = true
                    }
                })

            }
```

Comment: Firstly, you should post the whole function. Secondly, you should un-comment `forIndexPath` because you should be using it. Thirdly, you are calling two functions that run on a background thread. This isn't going to work. By the time they return, the cell is likely to have been reused for another row. Nevertheless, if only the first `mySpots` has a location, the `if let` will fail for all but the first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check your `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` first. The value you return inside is the number of row it will show and load in tableview.

And my cellForRowAtIndex is like this, I think yours should be alright also. Just check the number of row in section.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:MenuTableViewCell = tbvMenu.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("identifier") as! MenuTableViewCell
    let temp:String = MenuArr[indexPath.row] as! String
    cell.mainMenuTitle.text = temp
    return cell
}
```